# jQuery flash object click event not firing in IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, firefox, google-chrome

I'm just trying to understand a difference between IE, Chrome and Firefox. I have the following code on a page:

```
$('object').live('click', function(){
    alert('Fired');
});
```

I then populate the page with some Flash controls (in my case, I'm using Uploadify). When I click on the Flash control, I see the alert in Firefox 4. However, I do not see the alert in IE8 or Chrome (I havent tested any other browsers).

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could we see more code? This seems like it should work, so I can see why you're puzzled. Could be a syntactical error in your markup. Maybe try something like this, unless you have a specific reason for the `live()`.

```
$('object').click(function() {
    alert('Fired!');
});
```